# "No test is available" when attempting to run VSTest for a GoogleTest exe

Tags: c++, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, googletest

I have a C++ project that I am attempting to build and run using Azure Pipelines.

The build is working fine but I can't seem to get the unit tests to run in VSTest task using GoogleTest.

It was my understanding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest is installed (as per https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) so it can't be that.

Looking at the log I see:

No test is available in D:\a\1\s\Release\UnitTests.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I also attempted a Command Line Script task but running the UnitTests.exe just yields:

'UnitTests.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It seems your issue is similar to one https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/481

Comment: The local build on my PC works fine so I think it's linking ok. I am pretty sure it's a pipeline setup error on my part but the documentation is somewhat lacking for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the end by installing the Nuget package "GoogleTestAdapter" by Christian Soltenborn. All now seems to work fine but still very puzzled why this workaround is needed